# how to have multiple forms in a class based view

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms

I have a simple blog app that you can post news and blog on it. I wanted to show the latest posts on the main page, so I created this class like this:

```
class MainListView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'Blog/Home.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(MainListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['news'] = NEWS.objects.order_by('-published')[:2]
        context['posts'] = POSTS.objects.order_by('-published')[:3]
        return context
```

and it works great. however, I wanted to add two additional forms to the main page too. so I added these two functions to the class:

```
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.render_to_response({'aform': HomeGholakForm(prefix='aform_pre'), 'bform': 
            HomeContactForm(prefix='bform_pre')})

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        aform = _get_form(request, HomeGholakForm, 'aform_pre')
        bform = _get_form(request, HomeContactForm, 'bform_pre')
        if aform.is_bound and aform.is_valid():
            aform.save()
            return redirect('Home-Page')
        elif bform.is_bound and bform.is_valid():
            bform.save()
            return redirect('Home-Page')
        return self.render_to_response({'aform': aform, 'bform': bform})
```

and above this class I created a _get_form function in order for it to work:

```
def _get_form(request, formcls, prefix):
    data = request.POST if prefix in request.POST else None
    return formcls(data, prefix=prefix)
```

in the final stage I added the forms to my template like this:

```
         <form action="">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{bform.email}}
            <input type="submit" name="{{bform.prefix}}" class="btn"  />
            
        </form>
        <form action="">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{aform.info}}
            <input type="submit" name="{{aform.prefix}}" class="btn"  />
            
        </form>
```

After I did this, the forms both work fine, but the latest blog and news are not shown. what am I supposed to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`get_context_data` is normally called by the `get` or `post` method whichever is used (only `get` in `TemplateView`) and passed as the context while rendering. You override these methods but never call `get_context_data`. Change your get and post methods like so:

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    context = self.get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context.update({'aform': HomeGholakForm(prefix='aform_pre'), 'bform': HomeContactForm(prefix='bform_pre')})
    return self.render_to_response(context)

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    aform = _get_form(request, HomeGholakForm, 'aform_pre')
    bform = _get_form(request, HomeContactForm, 'bform_pre')
    if aform.is_bound and aform.is_valid():
        aform.save()
        return redirect('Home-Page')
    elif bform.is_bound and bform.is_valid():
        bform.save()
        return redirect('Home-Page')
    context = self.get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context.update({'aform': aform, 'bform': bform})
    return self.render_to_response(context)
```

You should consider making some Mixin along the lines of `FormMixin` which would make your work more easier.